# Regarding the dropping of the article "the" in this context

Tags: definite-article

In [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-insulator-and-dielectric-substance/answer/Rohit-Sammeta) answer to a physics question, the responder said,

> "The current J in a material is a combination of **conduction current** and **displacement current**".

Is it permissible to drop *the* in the above case? shouldn't it be:

> The current J in a material is a combination of *the* conduction current and *the* displacement current.

or even:

> The current J in a material is a combination of conduction current**s** and displacement current**s**.

?

Answer (score -1):

> Writers sometimes struggle with the choice to include an article or to
>   leave it out altogether. Keep in mind that if the noun is singular,
>   countable, and nonspecific or generic (e.g., book, author), the
>   articles a and an may be used. **However, if the noun is countable and
>   plural (e.g.., research studies) or uncountable (e.g., information)
>   and it is being used in a nonspecific or generic way, no article is
>   used.** [[1]](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/articles)

The following statement of yours;

> "The current J in a material is a combination of conduction current
>   and displacement current".

is a generic one where **current**, which is an **uncountable** noun, is used as a **general** concept both the times.

Therefore, no article should be used before them.

Comment: "conduction current" and "displacement current". are specific concepts and can have separate numerical measures. Use of the definite article, while not required, is proper and i think better writing.